# What is the most efficient way in Java to sign extend an arbitrary length pattern of bits?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, sign-extension

Let's say, for example, I have packed three 10 bit signed integers into a Java integer.

I can extract the 10 bits easily:

```
int unpacked = packed & 0x3FF;
packed >>= 10;
etc ...
```

But now I need to sign-extend the top bit (bit 9 from the right). Is there a quick way of doing this with resorting to testing the top bit and setting?

Perhaps there is a better way of unpacking that leaves the sign in place.

Comment: There are two possible values for the upper 32-10 bits - all '1's or all '0's.  So you can do this in one (conditional) step.

Comment: True - I'll correct my question, but can I do it without an if statement?

Comment: maybe I'm missing something, but what result should be for 0x2ff? (0b10 1111 1111)? is it -255 in decimal or -1052672 as per accepted answer?

Comment: I am querying that, but I think shift up and then down again will work if you get the numbers right.

Comment: @rghome shifting 0x2ff up and then down will give you -257 (0b1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110 1111 1111)

Comment: I think it needs to go up 22 and then down 22. There would be no need for the mask then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative to shifting twice is flipping the sign and then subtracting it:

```
int unpacked = packed & 0x3FF;
int extended = (unpacked ^ 0x200) - 0x200;
```

If the sign was not set, flipping it sets it and subtracting it resets it again.

If the sign was set, flipping it resets it, subtracting it sets it again but also borrows all the way to the top, setting all bits along the way.

This has some advantages,

- The code does not depend on the size of the target integer type, if `unpacked` and `extended` were `long` then the same thing would work.
- XOR and subtraction can be a little cheaper, for example on Skylake you can do 4 of those basic operations per cycle but only 2 shifts. The latency is the same though, and it only matters if the available ILP in the code is high.
- Shifts don't really algebraically combine, but XOR and subtraction can. For example if the next operation is to add some constant to `extended`, then that addition and the "subtract the sign" steps can be rolled into one operation.

Answer (score 4):

```
int signed = (packed << (32 - 10)) >> (32 - 10);
```

As `>>>` is the unsigned shift-right, and `>>` the signed shift-right.

*(I still had "bug", thanks @rghome)*

Comment: yes, `>>` is an arithmetic shift, so it'll sign-extend the value

Comment: I mean, the amount. Shifting up by 22 and down by 10 is a net shift of 12, which is not wanted.

Comment: @rghome I overlooked that very obvious error, like `* (32 - 10) / 10`. Thanks for clarifying.